# Solution on how to remove white space from top of website in a mobile phone browser like opera mini, single layout view

Tags: html, css, styles

I tried almost every online technique, but I still got the top space in my website, when ever i open it with opera mini mobile phone browser,single layout view, so i decided to try fix it on my own, and I got it right!

I realize when even you display a page in a single layout, it fits the website to the screen, and some css functions are disabled, since margin, padding, float and position functions are disabled automatically when you fit to screen, and the body always add inbuilt padding at the top. so i decieded to look for at least one function that works, guess what? "display". let me show you how!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    display: inline;
}

#top {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top">

<!-- your code goes here! -->

eg: <div id="header"></div>
<div id="container"></div> and so on..

<!-- your code goes here! -->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you use `html,body{margin:0;padding:0}`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried almost every online technique, but i still got the top space in my website, when ever i open it with opera mini mobile phone browser, so i decided to try fix it on my own, and i got it right!

i realize when even you display a page in a single layout, it fits the website to the screen, and some css functions are disabled, since margin, padding, float and position functions are disabled automatically when you fit to screen, and the body always add inbuilt padding at the top. so i decieded to look for at least one function that works, guess what? "display". let me show you how!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
display: inline;
}

#top {
display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top">

<!-- your code goes here! -->

eg: <div id="header"></div>
<div id="container"></div> and so on..

<!-- your code goes here! -->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you notice, the body{display:inline;} removes the inbuilt padding in the body, but without #top{display:inline-block;}, the div still wont display well, so you must include the `<div id="top">`
element before any code on your page! so simple.. hope this helps?